# What type to declare for useLoaderData(), and where?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I'm working on the NetNinja `react-router` in-depth #6 tutorial, but I'm trying to do it with typescript. I am fetching data from a JSON object, and I'm using the `useLoaderData()` hook and trying to map out the JSON object. I'm just not sure where to declare the type and/or which type to declare. Here is my component:

```js
import { NavLink, Link, Outlet, useLoaderData } from 'react-router-dom'

type Token = {
  id: number
  name: string
  ticker: string
  description: string
}

const Tokens = () => { 
  const tokens = useLoaderData()

  return ( 
    <div>
      <div>
        {tokens.map((token: Token) => (
          <Link to='/' key={token.id}>
            <p>{token.name}</p>
            <p>{token.ticker}</p>
            <p>{token.description}</p>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
      <nav>
        <NavLink to='uniswap'>Uniswap</NavLink>
        <NavLink to='balancer'>Balancer</NavLink>
      </nav>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
}

//loader function
export const tokensLoader = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:4000/tokens')

  return res.json()
}
 
export default Tokens;
```

The JSON object:

```json
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "uniswap",
      "ticker": "UNI",
      "description": "This is the description for Uniswap token"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "balancer",
      "ticker": "BAL",
      "description": "This is the description for Balancer token"
    }
  ]
}
```

My intuition felt like it should either be something like:

```js
const tokens: Token[] = useLoaderData()
```

or

```js
type TokenData = {
  tokens: Token[]
}

const tokens: TokenData = useLoaderData()
```

There is a lot going on and it is beyond my current understanding just following this tutorial. Which type should I be declaring and where?

Answer (score 5):

The return type of the `useLoaderData` hook is `unknown`.

See [Source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/4475b56d2e18014acfb8ff5f6077ff27df98d7fe/packages/react-router/lib/hooks.tsx#L852)

> ```
> export function useLoaderData(): unknown {
>   let state = useDataRouterState(DataRouterStateHook.UseLoaderData);
>   let routeId = useCurrentRouteId(DataRouterStateHook.UseLoaderData);
>
>   if (state.errors && state.errors[routeId] != null) {
>     console.error(
>       `You cannot \`useLoaderData\` in an errorElement (routeId: ${routeId})`
>     );
>     return undefined;
>   }
>   return state.loaderData[routeId];
> }
> ```

Just cast the return type to your `TokenData` type. Don't forget to destructure the `tokens` array that you'd like to map to JSX.

```js
export type Token = {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  ticker: string;
  description: string;
};

export type TokenData = {
  tokens: Token[];
};
```

```js
const { tokens } = useLoaderData() as TokenData;
```

Full example:

```js
import { NavLink, Link, Outlet, useLoaderData } from "react-router-dom";
import { Token, TokenData } from "./types";

const Tokens = () => {
  const { tokens } = useLoaderData() as TokenData;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {tokens.map((token: Token) => (
          <Link to="/" key={token.id}>
            <p>{token.name}</p>
            <p>{token.ticker}</p>
            <p>{token.description}</p>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </div>
      <nav>
        <NavLink to="uniswap">Uniswap</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="balancer">Balancer</NavLink>
      </nav>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit declaring-type-for-useloaderdata-which-type-to-declare-and-where]

Answer (score 1):

You can consider creating a type for `useLoaderData` and writing a wrapper for it:

```
// my-hooks/useLoaderData
import { useLoaderData as useLoaderDataOriginal } from 'react-router-dom'

interface UseLoaderDataHook {
  <T>():T
}

const useLoaderData:UseLoaderDataHook = () => {
  const useLoaderDataRef = useLoaderDataOriginal as UseLoaderDataHook
  return useLoaderDataRef()
}
```

Now you could use this hook in your component instead of original hook:

```
import {useLoaderData} from 'my-hooks/useLoaderData'

interface Car {
  id: string
  model: string
}

const CarComponent = () => {
    const car = useLoaderData<Car>() // use generic Car
    return <div>Car: {car.model}</div> // you have autocomplete here :)
}
```